# Treating specific check boxes as radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I am aware of the fact that checkboxes and radio buttons are two different types of data entry, and that wanting to use the one to be able to do the other is a bit like dressing up a cat to pretend it's a dog - but the way I want these checkboxes to operate there is no other way (I will show you later on).

I've created a data entry page where a member of staff can assign specific class qualifications to classes within the designated year group. The way these qualifications work is pretty straight forward: Multiple qualifications can be assigned to any class **EXCEPT ONE**: It is impossible for the same class to have both qualification EnAQA4700 and EnAQA4705.

So a class can have up to four qualifications at the same time (checkboxes, easy) with the 4700 and the 4705 being an exception; can be 4700, can be 4705, can be neither but **CANNOT** be both (radio buttons!)

Is it possible for the first two checkboxes (for EnAQA4700 and EnAQA4705) to be treated as radio buttons, but still able to be written into the database along with the other checkboxes?

Many thanks!

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML code for the first row of the table. You will see that the class name contains a PHP array variable and in one of my previous questions about checkboxes recognizing what class to write into using an array I was told to name the checkboxes accordingly.

```
<tr>
<td height="30"><?php echo $cl[0] ?></td>
<td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="Classes[<?php echo $cl[0]; ?>][]" id="checkbox"></td>
<td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="Classes[<?php echo $cl[0]; ?>][]" id="checkbox2"></td>
<td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="Classes[<?php echo $cl[0]; ?>][]" id="checkbox3"></td>
<td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="Classes[<?php echo $cl[0]; ?>][]" id="checkbox4"></td>
<td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="Classes[<?php echo $cl[0]; ?>][]" id="checkbox5"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML for that row and its checkboxes?

Comment: Posted an answer that *may* work right now, will make any necessary updates when the HTML is available.

Comment: I've added the HTML for the first row for you.

Comment: Updated my answer, and added a jsFiddle demo. The first two checkboxes should act like radio buttons, so you'll only be able to check one of them at a time; though unlike radio buttons, you'll have to uncheck the currently checked one before you can check the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to separate it from your HTML structure as much as possible would be to add a class, say `incompatible`, to the checkboxes in each row that aren't compatible with each other (only one of them can be selected at any one time). Then your jQuery would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.incompatible').on('change', function (e) {
        if($(this).closest('tr').find('.incompatible:checked').not(this).length > 0)
            this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

Essentially when you (try to) change the checked status of one of those checkboxes, it will look at the other checkboxes in that `<tr>` element to see if there are any that both have the class and are checked. If there's at least one of them, it sets the `checked` property of the changed checkbox to `false`.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XquDJ/)

Comment: How would I implement the JQuery into my page - I tried setting it within a <script type="javascript"></script> but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @SeanLimpens Need to make sure it executes after the elements exist, so use a `$(document).ready()` handler; updated the answer to include that. Note that I'm also assuming that the entire table exists at the time the page loads, if you're adding rows dynamically after that point this won't work.

Comment: Super - thanks! Yeah the table is not a dynamic echo, but a physical table laying out individual array results. I figured that, at the moment, for every subject we have available we have (roughly) the same amount of classes in the array so it'd make more sense to do it this way and allow more accessibility for our prototype.